# How can I add more than one UITableView in a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, scrollview

Here is my app.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/baozhiqiang/6943921630/
http://www.flickr.com/photos/baozhiqiang/6943921900/

You can see three buttons at the top of the main screen. When you click it, the gallery will change to next. They are not the same layout style.
I created it by making three ScrollView in a big ScrollView. Code like this:

```
[backgroundScrollView addSubview:innerNewsScrollView];
[backgroundScrollView addSubview:innerHotScrollView];
[backgroundScrollView addSubview:innerLinkScrollView];
```

And when click the button, I changed the frame of the ScrollView.

Now there is a problem, when I add more than 100 Pictures(UIButton with image) to the ScrollView, It had crashed. I want to use UITableView replace ScrollView. But how can I Control more than one UITableView in a UIViewController?

Anybody can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

- All the table view delegate methods include the table in question as one of the paramters, so it would simply be a case of checking which table is requesting data/information
- You don't *have* to point your table views to the view controller. Your view controller could store two objects whose only purpose is to repond to table view delegate methods

Unless the tables are trivial, I think the second option is the cleanest.

Comment: Thank you! 
How can I load more pictures when I scrolled at the bottom of the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Add all of your UITableViews in the UIViewController's view, set their `tag` properties to something you can distinct them and also set their delegates (usually `self` if your UIViewController implements the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol). Every method in the `UITableViewDelegate` passes `UITableView` reference as an argument and with the value of the tag property you can find out which table view is processed.